# finding if group of n consecutive numbers are repeating in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation, data-analysis

I want to find out if a set of n consecutive numbers are repeating for a particular partition.

Lets say I have `deviceIds` with some `recordid` whose value are in consecutive fashion each record that device generates is incremented by 1.

So I want to know if resetting the `recordid` and regenerating records with same sequence again. Lets understand by following table.

```
Device ID        recordid             DateTime
--------------------------------------------------
07777778999       2               18-12-2016 17:15
07777778123       10              18-12-2016 18:10
07777778123       10              18-12-2016 18:20
07777778999       3               19-12-2016 19:30
07777778999       4               19-12-2016 12:15
07777778999       5               19-12-2016 13:15
07777778999       6               20-12-2016 11:15
07777778123       11               20-12-2016 9:15
07777778123       12               20-12-2016 17:15
07777778123       13               20-12-2016 17:25
07777778123       14               20-12-2016 17:35
07777778999       7                20-12-2016 17:45
07777778999       8               20-12-2016 17:55
07777778999       4               20-12-2016 18:50
07777778999       5               20-12-2016 18:55 
07777778999       6               20-12-2016 18:50
07777778999       7               20-12-2016 18:55
...
```

There are many devices so we can partition it by devices and then apply our query to find if for a device, the numbers are regenerated like for example 07777778999, we had record id's 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and then the numbers are regenerated from 4,5,6,7, etc.

So i want to list down all the devices with such regeneration using SQL.
So the expected output for the above would be device 07777778999

Comment: have you tried using left join?

Comment: I don't get this '07777778999, we had record id's 2,3,4,5,6,7,8' and then 'numbers are regenerated from 4,5,6,7' - since the second batch does not start 2,3 and does not have 8 what logic do you have which says 07777778999 should be the expected output? Is it simply that recordid has been used more than once? in which case 07777778123 would be included (but you say you don't want that)?

Comment: Yes, the record values being repeated in sequence. If u see 778123, its 10,10,11,12,13,14 but for 7778999 its 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,4,5,6,7... its goes on it continues with that after 7 there is 8,9,10,11,12,13,etc basically first sequence stopped and then second sequence started at 4 and continued. Its basically a data analytics problem where we are trying to identify the devices for which the record id regeneration and reset itself to some value and tht is started

Comment: I wonder if anything would be lost in providing a simpler data set. 99 and 23 are, for instance, simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

This will return all the records, which has the regenerated values.

```
SELECT DeviceID,RecordId
FROM ResultSet
GROUP BY DeviceID,RecordId
HAVING COUNT(1)>1;
```

Comment: This does not give sequence. It only gives records which are duplicated for that device id. Suppose one record duplicates itself then that device will be listed

Comment: @230490, can you please provide some expected output.

Comment: So in the above example its device 07777778999 and not device 07777778123 though it has record 10 duplicated